# Spreading/dispersing overlapping points?

Tags: python, point, overlapping-features, matplotlib-basemap

I have a set of 150 sites globally, and I want to map them, and colour by a given variable. Unfortunately they are very non-uniformly distributed, with many of them in small clusters of only a few hundred meters. This means that with any reasonable sized markers on a map, the markers overlap a lot, and many of the markers can not be seen. I would like a way to spread out the markers (with lines connecting them to their original position), so that each marker can be seen without overlap. The exact position is not super important here, but the approximate global position is.

I'm using python with basemap/matplotlib, and I've tried a kind of force-directed approach that kind of works, but not very well. Here is an example:

[image]

```
As you can see, the European points are not very well un-overlapped.
The code for that spread is:

def spread_points(lat_lon, d=5, max_iter=300):

    new_lat_lon = lat_lon.copy(deep=True)

    dists = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(new_lat_lon, new_lat_lon)
    too_close = (0 < dists) & (dists < d)

    itr = 0
    while too_close.any() and itr < max_iter:
        itr += 1

        neighbour_means = []

        for i in range(len(new_lat_lon)):
            # for each point, find all "too close" points, and take their average.
            group_ind = too_close[i]
            if not group_ind.any():
                # no too close neighbours, use self.
                neighbour_means.append(new_lat_lon.iloc[i])
                continue
            group_ind[i] = True
            neighbour_means.append(new_lat_lon[group_ind].mean())

        max_diff = 0
        for i in range(len(new_lat_lon)):
            dir_grp_mean = (new_lat_lon.iloc[i] - neighbour_means[i])
            grp_dist = norm(dir_grp_mean)
            if grp_dist == 0:
                dir_grp_unit = 0
                grp_force = 0
            else:
                dir_grp_unit = dir_grp_mean / grp_dist
                grp_force = np.sqrt(d / grp_dist)

            # move each point away from the mean and toward home and jitter a tiny bit
            new_loc = new_lat_lon.iloc[i] \
                + grp_force * dir_grp_unit \
                - (new_lat_lon.iloc[i] - lat_lon.iloc[i]) / d \
                + np.random.randn(2) * 0.01 * d
            if not np.isfinite(new_loc).all():
                import ipdb
                ipdb.set_trace()
            max_diff = max(max_diff, norm(new_loc - new_lat_lon.iloc[i]))
            new_lat_lon.iloc[i] = new_loc

        if max_diff < d / 100:
            logger.info("Quitting after {i} iterations - differences are tiny")
            break

        dists = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(new_lat_lon, new_lat_lon)
        too_close = (0 < dists) & (dists < d)

    if itr == max_iter:
        logger.info("hit max_iter")

    return new_lat_lon
```

There is another algorithm in Inkscape called [`removeoverlaps`](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/src/libvpsc/rectangle.cpp#L563), which seems like it might work, but I'm having a hard time deciphering how it works. Edit: The results really aren't ideal anyway, because it moves points horizontally first then vertically, resulting in an odd layout:

[image: inkscape spread]

It would be much better if points were spread radially...

Are there any other algorithms for this kind of operation that already exist in or would be easy to implement in python?

Comment: I'd produce a reasonable size fishnet and place points in nearest vacant cell.

Comment: @FelixIP: interesting idea yeah, a hexagonal net might work well for that. Not sure how you would go about dealing with competition between points for a cell. For example, what would you do if you had 4+ points within a single triangle? (pretty sure that would happen in the above example in Europe if the net is large enough to avoid overlap).

Comment: Consider all cells vacant, place first point, mark cell as occupied. Go to next point, etc.

Comment: Right, but then your result is going to be highly dependant on how you initialise and iterate. For instance, if you have a bunch of neighbouring cells both with 4 points inside, the points in the first cell are going to be closest to their origin, and the later cell's points will be pushed further and futher away. I guess you could get around that by doing it randomly, and not sequentially (avoiding doing neighbours first).

Comment: @Felix. I tried this, and it worked well enough for me. Not perfect, for instance points that are not near other points still get moved unneccessarily. But close enough to at least see approximately where they are. And it looks kind of cool. Feel free to add this as an answer, and I'll accept it. My code is available at https://gist.github.com/naught101/d364b176b0646da9bf58198d79a0197d

Comment: Why don't you start with single point cells? Move point to center or leave unchanged. I use it in a past for placing labels in arcview 3:) Anyway please answer your own question, and add before and after pictures. Busy with something else...

Comment: @FelixIP: yeah, ok, that seems possible, but I guess this is close enough for me for now. I added an answer. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

Using FelixIP's comment as a starting point, I created a hexagonal grid, and then moved each point to the nearest grid cell. In order to avoid pushing, I used a hash of the site names pseudorandomly order the sites - this way the map is the same each time.

The results look like this:

[image: gridded map]

The code for this plot is available at https://gist.github.com/naught101/d364b176b0646da9bf58198d79a0197d, and requires a pandas dataframe with columns `lat, lon, c` (colour), and indexed by site name.

The grid size is arbitrary, I chose values that would suit the plot size.

This solution is not perfect. It does show all of the points in approximately the correct positions, but it also moves points that do not require moving.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much!